# clear cache to access new domain

Tags: caching, dns, digital-ocean

I've created a new domain using goDaddy. i've added this domain to my digitalocean server. This works great on my iphone, but when i try it on my browser it shows this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H6Si.png

I've asked DigitalOcean support where they told me to remove the old cache files. I've done this on my mac:

First I removed old cache files in my browser.

Then I wrote this in terminal:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Why it doesn't work like it does on my iphone where it shows the `index.html` file?

Comment: All you have done is flush the cache of your stub resolver; the old DNS RRs might also be cached in your ISP's (recursive) nameservers and will remain so until the TTL expires.  This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: ooh sorry did not know. So what you basically say is that i need to wait till TTL expires?

Comment: Well, you can have your computer override what it finds in DNS with a manually configured explicit IP address in `/etc/hosts` (or configure your computer to use resolvers that haven't yet cached old records) - but essentially yes, the "real" solution is to wait.